# Executing Javascript in Hyperlink formula Field

Tags: javascript, formula, formula-field

I currently have a custom button which has the following javascript :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}
var ref = "{!Proposal__Proposal__c.Id}"; 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("GenerateQuotePdfCont","saveQuotePdf",{parentId:"{!Proposal__Proposal__c.Id}"});
window.open('/apex/GenerateQuotePdfPage?scontrolCaching=1&id='+ref+'&scontrolCaching=1');
```

However, I would like to move this logic into a hyperLink function and then use it in a formula field like this :

```
IF (NOT ISBLANK(Configuration_Saved_Date__c) && Proposal__ReadyToGenerate__c && Grand_total_exclusive__c > 0, HYPERLINK("{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}
var ref = "{!Proposal__Proposal__c.Id}"; 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("GenerateQuotePdfCont","saveQuotePdf",{parentId:"{!Proposal__Proposal__c.Id}"});
window.open('/apex/GenerateQuotePdfPage?scontrolCaching=1&id='+ref+'&scontrolCaching=1');","_self"), NULL)
```

Is this something that is possible? Currently, the formula does not compile

Comment: I suspect this is actually an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe if you asked about what you're trying to accomplish, we could help out better. For example, do you need this to work in a list view? A related list? A report? Just on a detail page? Some things are more possible than others, so I'd recommend asking about the underlying problem directly.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I would like it work on a detail page. So the idea is to have a button inside a formula field on the detail page. On click, it attaches a pdf to the record and opens the pdf in a new window.

Comment: You could use a Custom Link instead of a Custom Button, or you could even drop the code in to a Visualforce page with a button in it, and drop the page on to the page layout.

Comment: so if i use a custom link, the logic above would work? I'm not quite sure how different that would be from a button

Comment: The difference between a link and a button is presentation. Links are in the detail area, while a button is near the top and bottom of the detail area (like Edit/Delete/etc). Likewise, VF pages can be put in an area in a way that it appears to be a field, although, obviously, it can't be shown in list views/reports.

Comment: oh Ok. the issue is that I would like it to be inside of a field on the layout.

Comment: Perhaps like the button I put in this demo? http://i.stack.imgur.com/OHSwN.png

Comment: @sfdcfox i would like something like these [demo](http://imgur.com/a/hJwWb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it isn't possible to have Javascript or Apex in a formula field.

When you create a formula field, the formula itself is stored in the database (as opposed to storing the result of the formula when it's evaluated). Every time you query a formula field, that formula is evaluated by the database, and the result made available to you.

This behavior is briefly explained in [An Introduction to Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas) in the Formula Limits section

> Formula fields are calculated using generated SQL on the backend. This SQL must not exceed 5000 characters. This includes other referenced formula fields. **[rest of section omitted]**

SQL can't execute or evaluate Javascript (there would be a ton of chaos if that were possible.) At best, your Javascript would be treated as plain text. At worst, your formula field won't compile.

Comment: but what about this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189347/javascript-hyperlink-formula-field

Answer (score 2):

At least with the HYPERLINK option it is possible to add javascript to a formula field. Refer to this blog post for adding javascript to `HYPERLINK()` option in formula fields: http://blog.adityanaag.com/16/Execute+Javascript+from+Formula+field

Comment: Any reason for downvote? Finding this blog post helped me with this issue so i just wanted to share it...

Comment: It's no longer valid because Salesforce will validate hyperlink with javascript starting Feb 17 .https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Spring ‘17 release in February 2017 this will not be available. They've already stated that it could give rise to a breach and malicious code inclusion. You can find info [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_cruc_no_javascript_in_hyperlink_functions.htm) and [here too](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1).