# Javascript Hyperlink formula field

Tags: javascript, formula-field

Is it possible to embed javascript in Hyperlink formula field to open a vf page in a pop up?Can you share the formula,if possible?

Comment: FYI: It will be disabled soon -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

> Use of formula field to open a visualforce page in Console and standard view page in Standard or Custom App. [applicable to Classic]

```
HYPERLINK("javascript:if(typeof(srcUp)=='function') {srcSelf('/apex/VisualforcePage?id=" & Id & "');} "+ 
" else {window.location.href='/" & Id & "'}" 
,Name 
, "_Parent" 
)
```

You can refer my blog post: [Different ways of navigation](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/different-ways-of-navigation.html)

Comment: Hi Santanu, I am trying to create formual field with the above code it is not letting me save by saving **Incorrect argument value for function 'HYPERLINK()'. Javascript is not allowed. (Related field: Formula)**. Can you help me with my question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906258/open-external-url-in-same-window-using-hyperlink-formula-in-salesforce-community?noredirect=1#comment96658757_54906258)